# Absolute alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
#main {
       position: relative;
       top:100px;
       left:100px;
       height:200;
       width:600;
       border:solid;
       border-width:1px;
    }
    
    
    .rightContain {
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
       right:0;
       border:solid;
       border-width:1px;
       width:10px;
    
    }
    
    .selector {
       position: relative;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       border:solid;
       border-color:blue;
       border-width:1px;
    }
    .selector > p {
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       line-height:70%;
    }
    
    .selectorBox {
       border:solid;
       border-width:1px;
       width:60px;
       height:60px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <div id="main">
          <div class="rightContain">
             <div class="selector">
                   <p>*</p>
                   <p>*</p>
                   <p>*</p>
             </div>
             <div class="selectorBox">
                item 
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm trying to get the .selectorBox top right corner to align to the bottom right of the .selector div. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `position:absolute` and `right:-1px` to the `#selectorBox`
and i believe it achieves the result you're looking for.

The `right` css can be changed to move the selectorBox to the left or right.

```css
#main {
       position: relative;
       top:100px;
       left:100px;
       height:200px;
       width:600px;
       border:solid;
       border-width:1px;
    }
    
    
    .rightContain {
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
       right:0;
       border:solid;
       border-width:1px;
       width:10px;
    
    }
    
    .selector {
       position: relative;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       border:solid;
       border-color:blue;
       border-width:1px;
    }
    .selector > p {
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       line-height:70%;
    }
    
    .selectorBox {
      position:absolute;
      right:-1px;
       border:solid;
       border-width:1px;
       width:60px;
       height:60px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <div id="main">
          <div class="rightContain">
             <div class="selector">
                   <p>*</p>
                   <p>*</p>
                   <p>*</p>
             </div>
             <div class="selectorBox">
                item 
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks yes that's what I want but I have to admit I don't understand it. I thought by making the .selectorBox absolute it would look for a parent element with relative to position against. Why does it take its position below the .selector?

Comment: @MarMan29 because we didnt give it a `top` position

Comment: So if you gave it no top or right position it will act like a relative positioned element until you start moving it?

Comment: @MarMan29 correct, but also when the other element is not positioned absolutely

Comment: Excellent Thanks for the help Pedro. Cool text profile btw ;)